# Is there any way to listen for a document fragment being attached to a document?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a program that puts some markup into a document fragment which can then be attached to the document. I would like to have some code execute when it has been attached, just like how the `connectedCallback` works on custom elements. Is this possible?

Attaching a document fragment to a document empties it, which means I could probably use a mutation observer, but then the code would execute if someone modified it before attaching it, which is not the behaviour I want.

Comment: Every time your code is called seems good enough to me.

Comment: @StackSlave accept when the code depends on the fragment being part of the bigger document at the time it's run.

Comment: Add to your fragment creating function which returns your `document.createDocumentFragment()`... like `function fragmentMaker(){  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(); /* append to frag then do whatever else you want */ return frag; }`

Comment: @StackSlave how does that help? I need to code to be executed when I do something like `document.body.appendChild(...)` not when the fragment is created.

Comment: `document.body.appendChild(fragmentMaker())`

Comment: @StackSlave but what if I want to premake the fragment and attach it at a later date.

Comment: A function only executes when you call it, which you will be doing when it's attached at a later date.

Comment: @StackSlave but `fragmentMaker` still couples the making of the fragment with the code that needs to execute when it's attached. For example: say the fragment takes 1 second worth of computation to build, and I want it to be inserted when someone presses a button. Using `fragmentMaker`, there would be a 1 second delay when that user presses the button. I want to be able to pre-make the fragment so it can be attached immediately when the button is pressed.

Comment: While the coupling is still there, the computation time will likely be in JS (or a synchronous call invoked therein) - not the native code / DOM insertion of the created fragment. So the hypothetical one second block will be result of the original creation, prior to an attempt to attach. If there is large creation the blocking can be mitigated with incremental creation (with the assumption that the building in JS is the slow-down) where such is done in subsequent timers.. the overall performance is slightly slower while the user experience can be made less frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone comes along and proves me wrong, I'm going to assume it's not possible to create someone that **only** triggers when the fragment is attached to a document. This, however, will activate when a fragment is attached to a document, and the only other thing that will activate it is if all the fragment's child nodes have been removed, something that seems very avoidable.

```js
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
frag.textContent = `I'm a document fragment`;
new MutationObserver(records => {
  if (!records[0].target.childNodes.length)
    console.log(`I've been attached!`); 
}).observe(frag, {childList: true});
```

```html
<button onclick='this.after(frag)'>Attach Fragment</button>
```

Comment: From the *short* question text: "*but then the code would execute if someone modified it before attaching it, which is not the behaviour I want.*"

Comment: @Kaiido I admit it's not perfect, but the only other way to trigger it is to remove every single one of its children, which seems acceptable for practical use.

Comment: Hum nope, simply `frag.textContent += "magical sentence that breaks your code";` will do.

Comment: @Kaiido that's because that operation deletes the text node (the only node that's in there) and replaces it with a new one. `frag.firstChild.textContent += 'boring sentance that works just fine';` does not trigger the `console.log`.

Comment: Yes, but then your assertion "the only other way to trigger it is to remove every single one of its children" is wrong, that's what my comment pointed out. Now you are the asker, so you are the one able to decide if indeed this "seems acceptable for practical use", but this answer goes against the quote in my first comment. (+ it is certainly not the only way to trigger false positives).

Comment: @Kaiido you actually made me realize something to improve it so thank you. I was using `node.children` which is only elements. Switching to `node.childNodes`, it now handles the code in your comment just fine.

Comment: @Kaiido also you are correct that my code does not adhere to what I wanted. But sometimes what you want just isn't possible, in which case I think it is appropriate to answer with something that isn't exactly perfect, but still may do the job the asker wants to accomplish.

Comment: Then your answer should clearly state "There doesn't seem to be any way to know when this happens, the closest I could come is to check if there are still content in the fragment when a MutationEvent occurs.". Just giving the code of an non-optimal solution is not a good answer.